# How do I debug a merge sort?

Tags: c, recursion

I know what merge sort is and I have executed it before. But often when I try doing this sort, I almost never get the desired answer. Best as I can guess, I have trouble storing the final sorted array.

How can I debug this and what is the approach to debug any similar recursion problems?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

void merge(int arr[],int p,int q,int r)
{
    int n1= q-p+1;//1st half
    int n2= r-(q+1)+1;//2nd half
    int arr2[100];
    int n=p;

    int ar1[n1],ar2[n2];
    for(int i=p;i<=q;i++)
    {
        ar1[i]=arr[p+i];
    }
    for(int i=q+1;i<=r;i++)
    {
        ar1[i]=arr[p+i];
    }
    int i,j;

    for(i=0,j=0;i<n1&&j<n2;)
    {
        if(ar2[j]<ar1[i]){arr2[n]=ar2[j];j++;}

        else {arr2[n]=ar1[i];i++;}

        n++;
}

while (i<=n1)
{
    arr[n]=ar1[i];
    n++;
}
while (j<=n2)
{


    arr[n]=ar2[j];
        n++;
    }
    if(p==0&&r==9)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",arr2[i]);
        }
    }
}
void mergesort(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    if(p<r)
    {
        int q=(p+r)/2;
        mergesort(arr,p,q);
        mergesort(arr,q+1,r);
        merge(arr,p,q,r);
    }   
}


int main()
{
    int arr[]={2,4,13,4,0,23,54,12,6,9};
    mergesort(arr,0,9);
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a debugger?

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Sort an empty array.  Sort 1 element.  Sort 2 different elements in both orders, then two identical elements.  Sort 3 elements that are out-of-order.  Use many printf() calls, or debug breakpoints and variable inspections, to follow the operations.  If you do just those simple cases and get them 100% working, no edge-cases and no segfaults etc, you will have eliminated 99% of all household bugs.

Comment: 'whats the approach to debug any similar recursion problems?' - hard work with the debugger and logger.  Use simplified test cases.  It's like digging ditches - you have to pick up a shovel and start moving dirt.

Comment: It's perhaps not the only error, but you never store anything in `ar2` but still use it.

Comment: I suggest that you read the code of `merge` very carefully, verifying that each statement does what it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My overall comment is "neatness counts" and your `merge()` code is a mess.  Don't you see that you take things out of `ar2` but never put anything into it?  Also, `arr2` isn't needed so get rid of it.  And your indexes are all wrong.

Your indentation is worthless, how do you expect to debug anything?  (Besides getting folks on SO to do it for you.)  Think about each line: does it build on the previous statements; does it build towards the following statements?  Think about each index: where does it begin; where should it end?  Your code untwisted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int array[], int p, int q, int r)
{
    int n1 = q - p + 1; // 1st half
    int n2 = r - (q + 1) + 1; // 2nd half

    int ar1[n1], ar2[n2];

    for (int i = p, j = 0; j < n1; i++, j++)
    {
        ar1[j] = array[i];
    }

    for (int i = q + 1, j = 0; j < n2; i++, j++)
    {
        ar2[j] = array[i];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, n = p;

    for (; i < n1 && j < n2; n++)
    {
        if (ar2[j] < ar1[i])
        {
            array[n] = ar2[j++];
        } else {
            array[n] = ar1[i++];
        }
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        array[n++] = ar1[i++];
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        array[n++] = ar2[j++];
    }
}

void mergesort(int array[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        mergesort(array, p, q);
        mergesort(array, q + 1, r);
        merge(array, p, q, r);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {2, 4, 13, 4, 0, 23, 54, 12, 6, 9};

    int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);

    mergesort(array, 0, length - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```